# There are $450$ students in our class. I have to choose the students who are ranked in the $80$th percentile or above.

Tags: statistics, means

There are $450$ students in our class. I have to choose the students who are ranked in the $80$th percentile or above.

Which measure of average would be the most meaningful – mean, median, mid-range, or mode? Do we at all need any measure of average?

can anyone please help me ?

Comment: How many students are in the 80th percentile? And the 80th percentile of *what*? Grades? A particular score? If you have access to these scores, just put them in order and pick the highest ninety...

Comment: Are you asking for help with definitions? With the criterion for ranking students?  Or something else?  The median is the 50th percentile, so that's most closely related to finding which students are "ranked in the 80th percentile or above," but your problem statement does not include enough information to respond more specifically.

Comment: "$80$th percentile and above" means the top quintile, the best $90$ students out of the $450$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to decide what kind of score you will
use to represent a student's accomplishments in a class.
That score could be based on the mean of three exams,
the median of five exams, the highest score among four
exams, or whatever the instructor thinks is the best
measure of student performance.

Then you will have $n = 450$ scores. Sort then from
smallest to largest. Roughly speaking, the 80th percentile will lie at
the the $360$th of the sorted scores. The top $90$
scores will be at or above the 80th percentile.

If scores are integers, then it is possible to have
several sorted scores tied at the 89th percentile. If
that happened, you would have to decide whether to
include all or none of the students with these tied
scores. So if you know in advance you will be interested
in percentiles, it is best not to round scores to be integers.

**Example in R without rounding:**

```
set.seed(223)
x = 100*rbeta(450, 7, 3)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  17.45   59.79   70.72   68.75   79.44   96.30 
quantile(x, .8)
     80% 
82.22081
```

Here is a stripchart of all 458 scores with a vertical red line at the 80th percentile:

```
stripchart(x, pch="|")
abline(v = 82.22, col="red")
```

[image]

The plot is somewhat congested around the 80th percentile,
so let's take a detailed look at the actual values in
the vicinity of the 90th percentile. We begin by
sorting the 450 scores from smallest to largest.
Then we print scores in positions 355 to 365.

```
x.s = sort(x)
x.s[355:365]
[1] 81.84596 81.98908 82.17073 82.17978 82.21221 82.22057
[7] 82.22177 82.23840 82.32506 82.38705 82.59776
```

The 80th percentile  $82.22081$ is between scores $82.22057$ and $82.221777.$ There are no ties, so there is no ambiguity about drawing the line between the lower 80% and the upper 20% of the sample. [Caution: Various statistical computer programs and textbooks have slightly different
ways of giving an *exact* value at the 'borderline' between scores of rank 360 and 361, but that usually makes no practical difference in interpretation.]

**With rounding to integers:**

Call the rounded scores `y` and the sorted rounded scores `y,s`:

```
y.r = round(x.s)
summary(y.s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  17.00   60.00   71.00   68.77   79.00   96.00 
quantile(y.s, .80)
80% 
 82

stripchart(y.s, ylim=c(-.2,20), meth="stack", offset=1/6, pch="-")
 abline(v=82, col="red")
```

[image]

Now, the 80th percentile is at rounded score $82.$ However,
several students have rounded score $82.$ To be precise, there are 14 scores tied at $82.$

```
sum(y.s == 82)
[1] 14

y.s[350:365]
[1] 81 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 83
```

So we have a choice to include or exclude score $82$
among the "top 20%". Inclusion leads to 80.89% below
and exclusion leads to 77.78% below.

```
mean(y.s < 82);  mean(y.s <= 82)
[1] 0.7777778
[1] 0.8088889
```

In the grand scheme of things the difference may not matter. But if the "top 20%" get A's and those just
below get B's, it will matter to the 14 students tied
at the borderline. So it is a good idea to realize
there there may be ties at the borderline and to
have a clear policy how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're actually running a class**

The median would be most helpful to understand. Let's suppose you have homework assignments (30%), quizzes (5%), midterms (25%), and finals (40%) for students and you weighted those to come up with a score for each student $S$ between 0 and 100. Now you sort the scores and find the scores that are at the 225th and 226th. These are the medians. Or you could take the average of them which is common. That is the median score. It is the 50th percentile score. Anyone who scored above the median is in the top 50th percentile. Now do the same thing for the 80th percentile. You have 450 students: $450*.8=360$ so take the average of the 360th and 361th score to find the 80th percentile score. Anyone who scored above that score is in the top 80th percentile of the class.